# How to find Private Key Location

Tags: ssh, server, private-key

I'm trying to access a server using Filezilla and was told I needed to use authentication with public/private keys. I created the keys using the Terminal, but cannot find them on my computer.

This is where the key is located: 
(/Users/ed/.ssh/id_rsa)

I checked in my home directory, but the folder .ssh is nowhere to be found. Is there a secret place .ssh folder is stored and how can I access it?

My Mac runs on OS X ElCaptain. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Since the directory is starting with a dot it might be hidden from your attempts to find it. Did you try to `cd /Users/ed/.ssh/ ; ls` right into it?

Comment: "I checked in my home directory, but the folder .ssh is nowhere to be found" Could you describe exactly what you did to look for this directory?

Comment: I went to my finder and clicked the home icon. When I try `cd /Users/ed/.ssh/ ; ls` it says there's no such file or directory.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Files and folders starting with a period (.ssh) are hidden by default. To find private/public key, run this commands:

```
ls -a
```

In your case, run this commands to find the ssh keys:

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

then:

```
ls -a
```

Now you should see the keys like this:

```
.       ..      id_rsa      id_rsa.pub
```

If the keys are not there then definitely you need to create the key by `ssh-keygen` command.

Comment: in my ubuntu : bash: cd: id_rsa: No such file or directory. Just known_hosts file

Comment: @quangkid in such case, either SSH keys were not set up (you have to manually generate them, remember did you do it) or they're located elsewhere. Also, the `id_rsa` is a _file_, not folder, you should not `cd` into it. If it helps, you can open the file in the terminal via a desktop application, for example, if you've got Sublime Text, that would be `subl id_rsa`. Similar for vscode or atom, they have their own "call names".

Comment: @quangkid If the keys are not there then definitely you need to create the key by ssh-keygen command.

Answer (score 5):

(MacOS) I my case, .ssh folder was hidden so I went to folder route (example  /Users/syed.dastagir)and pressed `Command + Shift + . (full stop/period)` and it showed me .ssh folder.

When you no longer want to see the hidden folders just press Command + Shift + . again.

Answer (score 2):

If using Finder, I used defaults

Terminal

```
write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true [Press Return] 
killall Finder
```

Then I was able to see .ssh directory in Finder at

```
/Users/MYUSERNAME/.ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

when referencing the private key name, when setting up the config file for GitHub for example ( https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent ), I thought I needed an id with number, i.e 'id_43248390', however I just needed to reference 'id_rsa'.

This is incase any gets blocked similarly.